Inlay Hints and IntelliSense for Custom XAML Properties
I'm trying to implement some custom controls and I want to use a custom property type Placement. I've already prepared a TypeConverter implementation that works. However, both Rider and Visual Studio don't provide any inlay hints or IntelliSense when writing XAML for my custom property.
This is how my custom property type works.
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Wpf.Controls;

[TypeConverter(typeof(PlacementConverter))]
public readonly struct Placement(double horizontalOffset, double verticalOffset)
{
    internal const double DefaultOffset = 50.0;

    public static Placement Right { get; } = new(DefaultOffset, 0.0);
    public static Placement Top { get; } = new(0.0, DefaultOffset);
    public static Placement Left { get; } = -Right;
    public static Placement Bottom { get; } = -Top;
    public static Placement TopRight { get; } = Top + Right;
    public static Placement TopLeft { get; } = Top + Left;
    public static Placement BottomRight { get; } = Bottom + Right;
    public static Placement BottomLeft { get; } = Bottom + Left;

    public double HorizontalOffset { get; } = horizontalOffset;
    public double VerticalOffset { get; } = verticalOffset;
    
    public static Placement operator +(Placement left, Placement right)
    {
        return new(
            horizontalOffset: left.HorizontalOffset + right.HorizontalOffset,
            verticalOffset: left.VerticalOffset + right.VerticalOffset);
    }

    public static Placement operator -(Placement left, Placement right)
    {
        return new(
            horizontalOffset: left.HorizontalOffset - right.HorizontalOffset,
            verticalOffset: left.VerticalOffset - right.VerticalOffset);
    }

    public static Placement operator +(Placement original)
    {
        return new(+original.HorizontalOffset, +original.VerticalOffset);
    }

    public static Placement operator -(Placement original)
    {
        return new(-original.HorizontalOffset, -original.VerticalOffset);
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out double horizontalOffset, out double verticalOffset)
    {
        (horizontalOffset, verticalOffset) = (HorizontalOffset, VerticalOffset);
    }
}

This is how my TypeConverter works.
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Wpf.Controls;

public class PlacementConverter : TypeConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(new[]
        {
            Placement.Right,
            Placement.Top,
            Placement.Left,
            Placement.Bottom,
            Placement.TopRight,
            Placement.TopLeft,
            Placement.BottomRight,
            Placement.BottomLeft
        });
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
    {
        return value is string strValue
            ? Convert(strValue)
            : base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    private static Placement Convert(string strValue)
    {
        return strValue.Trim().ToUpper() switch
        {
            "RIGHT" => Placement.Right,
            "TOP" => Placement.Top,
            "LEFT" => Placement.Left,
            "BOTTOM" => Placement.Bottom,
            "TOPLEFT" => Placement.TopLeft,
            "TOPRIGHT" => Placement.TopRight,
            "BOTTOMLEFT" => Placement.BottomLeft,
            "BOTTOMRIGHT" => Placement.BottomRight,
            _ => Parse(strValue)
        };
    }

    private static Placement Parse(string strValue)
    {
        var trimmed = strValue.Trim();
        var parts = trimmed.Split(' ');

        if (parts.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Value '{strValue}' must have exactly two offsets (horizontal and vertical)!");

        if (!double.TryParse(parts[0], out var horizontalOffset))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Value '{strValue}' has a non-numeric horizontal offset!");

        if (!double.TryParse(parts[1], out var verticalOffset))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Value '{strValue}' has a non-numeric vertical offset!");
        
        return new(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type? destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string)
               || destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)
               || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override object? ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object? value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is not Placement placement)
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return placement switch
            {
                (Placement.DefaultOffset, 0.0) => "Right",
                (0.0, Placement.DefaultOffset) => "Top",
                (-Placement.DefaultOffset, 0.0) => "Left",
                (0.0, -Placement.DefaultOffset) => "Bottom",
                (Placement.DefaultOffset, Placement.DefaultOffset) => "TopRight",
                (-Placement.DefaultOffset, Placement.DefaultOffset) => "TopLeft",
                (Placement.DefaultOffset, -Placement.DefaultOffset) => "BottomRight",
                (-Placement.DefaultOffset, -Placement.DefaultOffset) => "BottomLeft",
                _ => $"{placement.HorizontalOffset} {placement.VerticalOffset}"
            };
        }

        if (destinationType != typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        
        var constructorInfo = typeof(Placement).GetConstructor([typeof(double), typeof(double)]);
        var constructorArgs = new object[] { placement.HorizontalOffset, placement.VerticalOffset };
        return new InstanceDescriptor(constructorInfo, constructorArgs);
    }
}

I used ThicknessConverter as a blueprint for implementing my PlacementConverter. I only support converting to InstanceDescriptor for that reason. I don't know what it's used for, but I assumed this is what the IDE can use to understand the property value and provide IntelliSense suggestions.
I can use it on my custom control like Placement="TopRight" or Placement="50 50". However, I don't see the inlay hint like I do for Margin, for example. I also don't get any suggestions when typing the property's value.
Are custom properties not supported to that degree by the IDE or am I missing something?
I've looked at the markup extensions documentation, but it looks like it doesn't do what I want to achieve. In the type converters documentation I didn't find any useful information about IntelliSense support or inlay hints.
Edit: At @HuiLiu's request, here's a screenshot of the expected behavior in Rider.

As you can see, the Button's Margin property has some inlay hints on which number is which margin side. When I edit the HorizontalAlignment property, I get suggestions for the usable values. I am aware that HorizontalAlignment uses an enum type and I get suggestions if I use a custom enum type. I just assumed that it would also work for struct types if I implemented GetStandardValuesSupported and GetStandardValues.
The actual behavior is that I don't see any inlay hints at all and I don't get any suggestions when typing the value of the Placement attribute.
In Visual Studio I don't see the inlay hints for Margin, so I assume this is not something that Visual Studio supports. Here I also see the enum values for HorizontalAlignment, but not for Placement.


Note: I renamed HandPlacement to Placement for this post, but I didn't realize it's now different in the screenshot. HandPlacement is identical to Placement in the code above.


Hi,@G_hi3. Could you share your expected results and actual results?
